# I've been learning how to use Django, and I'm triying to create objects in python shell but the command "python manage.py shell" isn't working for me

Tags: python, django

Rozinas-MacBook-Air:website Benoni$ python manage.py shell

```
  File "manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use `python3 manage.py shell`.

Comment: active the env and type `./manage.py shell`

Comment: What version of python do you get when you type `python` on your macbook?

Comment: Python 2.7.10 .

Comment: @BenoniEsckinder: you should use `python3`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you start a [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) interpreter, and you try to run a Django server that has been constructed for [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x). In that case it raises an error. It also does not make much sense to use [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) anymore, since updates are no longer made since January 1<sup>st</sup>, 2020.

You can run this with `python3` to run a Django shell with a [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) interpreter, or better is to make a virtual environment, for example with [`virtualenv` [Python-doc]](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#installing-virtualenv) for Python-3.x.

For that virtual environment, one can install Django for that virtual environment. You can then activate that virtual environment with `. env/bin/activate`, given that you constructed a virtual environment named *`env`*, and then run the interpreter provided for that virtual environment. This guarantees that you will use the right Python interpreter, and that that interpreter has all the necessary packages (together with a specific version), and thus prevent running it and require packages that have only been installed system-wide.